# Mathematical methods of map making?

Tags: cartography

I am in high-school and we have an assignment to be submitted. It's basically choosing a topic that interests you and explore that in a depth way. I am interested in map making and the mathematics around it. Do any of you have any suggestions/leads for me to go about my assignment because I am totally clueless. All the help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using wrong tags is not well accepted here. Besides, you should now that the displine that deals with making maps is Cartography. I've edited your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The references in the Wikipedia article on [map projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) are a very good place to start.  In particular, the book by Snyder, [An album of map projections](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1453) is wonderful.

Mathematicians are particularly taken with the idea of *conformal projections*. You might take this as a mini-project: what are they, and why are they important.